# React router history push not working with #

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to build a react app, the react routes have '#' in them to navigate to different sections, It is working fine when I navigate them by clicking on navbar, but
If I use history.push('/home#aboutus')
this is navigating to home but not moving to the aboutus section.
If I use history.push({pathname: "/home#home",userData: data})
only the URL is updating, the screen in empty.

PS: have enclosed this component within Router in parent component

Please refer to the below-attached code.

```
<div>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <Header />
      </div>{" "}
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/package"
          exact
          render={(props) => {
            console.log("inside package");
            return <Package {...props} />;
          }}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/home"
          render={(props) => {
            console.log("inside home");
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <div id="home">
                  <Home />
                </div>
                <div id="facility">
                  <Facility />
                </div>
                <div id="speciality">
                  <Special />
                </div>
                <div id="about">
                  <About {...props} />
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          }}
        />
        <Route
          path="/specialties/:specality"
          exact
          component={(props) => {
            console.log("inside speciality");
            return <SpecialDetail {...props} />;
          }}
        />
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md#to-object) component, it supports a `hash` parameter which takes the `id` to navigate to.

Comment: already tried bro, still the same result. It is just redirecting to the home page but not to the about section.